# Execute python code and evaluate/test results

Tags: python

Admittedly I am not sure how to ask this, as I know how to handle this in R (code execution in a new environment), but equivalent searches for the python solution are not yielding what I was hoping.

In short, I will receive a spreadsheet (or csv) where the contents of the column will contain, hopefully, valid python code.  This could be the equivalent of a script, but just contained in the csv/workbook.  For a use case, think teaching programming and the output is an LMS.

What I am hoping to do is loop over the file, and for each cell, run the code, and with the results in memory, test to see if certain things exist.

For example:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D-zC10rUTuozfTR5yHfauIGbSNe-PmfrZCkC7UTPH1c/edit?usp=sharing

When evaluating the first response in the spreadsheet above, I would want to test that x, y, and z are all properly defined and have the expected values.

Because there would be multiple rows in the file, one per student, how can I run each row separately, evaluate the results, and ensure that I isolate the results to only that cell.  Simply, when moving on, I do not retain any of the past evaluations.

Comment: you are looking for [`exec` built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), you can pass a string code and a dictionary to use as variable namespace so you can inspect it as a normal dictionary. Are you asking about security measures or is that sufficient?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen that might do the trick, I wasn't aware as I come to python from a data science point of view.  Let me take a peak.

Answer (score 2):

(I am unaware of tools to do code checking, so I am dealing with it in a very manual way.)

It is possible to use Python's `exec()` function to execute strings such as the content in the cells.

Ex:

```
variables = {}
exec("""import os

# a comment
x = 2 
y = 6
z = x * y""", variables)
assert variables["z"] == 12
```

Dealing with the csv file:

```
import csv

csv_file = open("path_to_csv_file", "rt")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
iterator = iter(csv_reader)
next(iterator) # To skip the titles of the columns

for row in iterator:
    user = row[0]
    answer = row[1]

### Any other code involving the csv file must be put here to work properly,
### that is, before closing csv_file.

csv_file.close() # Remember to close the file.
```

It won't be able to detect whether some module was imported (Because when importing from an `exec()` function, the module will remain in cache for the next exec's). One way to test this would be to 'unimport' the module and test the exec for Exceptions.
Ex:

```
# This piece of code would be before closing the file,
# INSIDE THE FOR LOOP AND WITH IT IDENTED (Because you want
# it to run for each student.).

try:
    del os # 'unimporting' os (This doesn't 'unimport' as much as deletes a
           # reference to the module, what could be problematic if a 'from
           # module import object' statement was used.)
except NameError: # So that trying to delete a module that wasn't imported
                  # does not lead to Exceptions being raised.
    pass

namespace = dict()
try:
    exec(answer, namespace)
except:
    # Answer code could not be run without raising exceptions, i.e., the code
    # is poorly written.

    # Code you want to run when the answer is wrong.
else:
    # The code hasn't raised Exceptions, time to test the variables.

    x, y, z = namespace['x'], namespace['y'], namespace['z']
    if (x == 2) and (y == 6) and (z == x * y):
        # Code you want to run when the answer is right.
    else:
        # Code you want to run when the answer is wrong.
```

I sense that this is not the best way to do this, but it is certainly an attempt.
I hope this helped.

EDIT: Removed some bad code and added part of Tadhg McDonald-Jensen's comment.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I can certainly use bits of this.  I wasn't aware of exec and the ability to store the namespace as a dict for further inspection.  I think between these, I have enough to run with.

Comment: technically `del os` doesn't actually unimport the module, you'd have to do something like `del sys.modules["os"]` but at that point you might as well just spawn subprocess to run each one so you can monitor stdout and reset all modules every time, but that is probably super overkill for what you are wanting so the way you got it is fine :)